# PHP + AJAX send data (link) trouble

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, url-encoding

I use my own AJAX code to send data, it worked, AJAX sent & PHP code gets a variable, but:

When I try send a link ( ex: http://abc.com/abc+/ ) or var like folder name has `+` it return string without `+`.

AJAX sends data as `&data='+encodeURIComponent(data)+'` and PHP gets `urldecode($data);`

My problem is how to get PHP get variable from POST data without removing the `+` char from my string.

Comment: Have you tried URL-encoding the +?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`rawurldecode()`](http://php.net/rawurldecode) in PHP. [`rawurldecode()`](http://php.net/rawurldecode) does not decode plus symbols (+) into spaces while [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode) does.

This way, whether your JavaScript sends the plus character as the literal string `+` or as the encoded string `%2B`, PHP will decode it as a plus character.

Answer (score 0):

`+` is special meaning character when used in URLs and substitutes space (). If you want to pass `+` literaly you have to encode it (to `%2b`) as well. In general, you should always pass whatever is used to build URL thru `urlencode()` to avoid problems.

See what is it all about:

```
echo urlencode(' + ');   // spaces around `+`
```

gives

```
+%2B+
```

More about url encoding in [RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html) or [PHP docs](http://php.net/urlencode)